# T-SQL search through all columns for jquery autocomplete textbox

Tags: jquery, sql-server, t-sql, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have been trying to design a query to search for specific text through all columns but it is not working as required.

Here is my query:

```
create table #tblTempAddress (locationId int identity(1,1) primary key, postcode nvarchar(300), road nvarchar(1000), ApartmentName nvarchar(1000), district nvarchar(200), Village nvarchar(200), City nvarchar(200))

insert into #tblTempAddress values ('DY4 8QJ','Union Street',NULL,'Tipton',NULL,NULL)
insert into #tblTempAddress values ('DY4 9JP','Phillips Court','Union Street','Princes End',NULL,NULL)
insert into #tblTempAddress values ('DY4 9JR','Union Street','Princes End','Tipton',NULL,NULL)
insert into #tblTempAddress values ('DY8 1PJ','Union Street',NULL,'Stourbridge',NULL,NULL)
insert into #tblTempAddress values ('DY8 1PR','Union Street',NULL,'Stourbridge',NULL,NULL)
insert into #tblTempAddress values ('DY9 8BJ','Union Street','Lye','Stourbridge',NULL,NULL)
insert into #tblTempAddress values ('B65 0EL','Union Street',NULL,'Rowley Regis',NULL,NULL)
insert into #tblTempAddress values ('B65 0ER','Union Street',NULL,'Rowley Regis',NULL,NULL)
insert into #tblTempAddress values ('DY2 8PJ','Union Street',NULL,'Dudley',NULL,NULL)
insert into #tblTempAddress values ('DY2 8PP','Union Street',NULL,'Dudley',NULL,NULL)


declare @searchtext nvarchar(1000)
set @searchtext = 'union street'
select top 10 postcode, road, ApartmentName, District, Village, City from #tblTempAddress    
where road like '%' + @searchtext + '%'        
OR ApartmentName like '%'+ @searchtext + '%'    
OR District like '%'+ @searchtext + '%'    
OR Village like '%'+ @searchtext + '%'    
OR City like '%'+ @searchtext + '%'    
OR postcode like '%' + @searchtext + '%'
```

When I set the @searchtext to "union street" it returns all data related to "union street" but when I add "lye" like `@searchtext = 'union street lye'` then its not showing result related to union street Lye which is on the row number 6.
I have gone through [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1522/searching-and-finding-a-string-value-in-all-columns-in-a-sql-server-table/) blog but no help.

Comment: Note, please be careful with SQL injection possibilities here! (Use parameters)

Comment: _"but when I add "lye" like @searchtext = 'union street lye' then its not showing result related to union street Lye_" Because it's really there is no column has the string `'union street lye'`

Comment: I concat all columns to search but still not working.. CONCAT(ApartmentName,'', road,'',District, '', Village, '', City, '', postcode) like '%' + @searchtext + '%'

Comment: you have concat road and apartmentName, but may be user can enter "lye union street" or "union street stourbridge", or with postcode, in those cases, it will not work.

Comment: @dawncode, I would suggest 1> You first go through what LIKE operator in SQL does, 2> What string you are looking for (subset string) in which parent string. Once you have the understanding of these 2 things, I am pretty sure you will be able to re-write the query (you are close, and just missing the understanding of the above 2 points I mentioned).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
--your table declaration here
declare @searchtext nvarchar(1000)
set @searchtext = 'union street in lye'

;with keywords as (
select value from string_split(@searchtext,' ') --tokenize @searchtext
except
select * from string_split('and or a an the for at on in why how when to from',' ')--exclude stop words
),
kwcount as (
select COUNT(value) total from keywords
),
matches as (
select t.locationId
,COUNT(distinct value) cnt
from #tblTempAddress t
inner join keywords on concat(postcode,' ', road,' ', ApartmentName,' ', district,' ', Village,' ', City) like '%'+keywords.value+'%'
group by t.locationId
)
select top 10 postcode, road, ApartmentName, District, Village, City 
from #tblTempAddress t
inner join matches m on t.locationId=m.locationId
cross join kwcount c
where m.cnt=c.total --require match all keywords in @searchtext. weaker filter may be used
order by m.cnt desc
```

The query may give some false positives so filter tuning is desired.
Also FullText search could be very helpful.